# Enable Multidex

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I used to receive `DexIndexOverflowException` a couple of days ago and what I did is :

a) adding `multiDexEnabled true` to defaultConfig in my `build.gradle` file.

b) adding `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` in the dependencies section.

and after that everything is running OK again.

Today I was reading `multidex` user guide in d.android.com site ( link [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) ) and it says that I should also override `MultiDexApplication` class (since I already extend from `Application` ).

My question is : since I'm not extending `MultiDexApplication` how is it possible, by doing only the two things I mentioned above, not to receive the Exception I was receiving before ? And what should I do now ? Should I try and extend `MultiDexApplication` even if now everything is OK?

Comment: have you tested your app with a pre lolipop device?

Comment: Yes I did and its working without any problems

Comment: May be you are not over 65536 methods for dex  Check also the doc: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1887/multidex-and-the-dex-method-limit/6155/enabling-multidex#t=20170420104458307849

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be near in the number limit of methods, i recomend make the total implementation. Otherwise you can review your dependencies and remove those you are not using and use ProGuard. Good pratice is helpfull, like prefer use methods `private` when possible.

You have some possibilities to use MultiDex.

> Minimal MultiDex capable application. To use the legacy multidex
>   library there is 3 possibility:
>
> - Declare this class as the application in your AndroidManifest.xml.
> - Have your Application extends this class.
> - Have your Application override attachBaseContext starting with protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) { super.attachBaseContext(base); MultiDex.install(this);

The last one should fit for you.

Comment: so could you please explain why it is working for him without any of these?

Comment: I'm assuming the final dex dont have more than 65536 or he is only considering Instant run builds. To verify this: First make sure you are compiling a final APK. After a final APK built, In Android Studio go to menu Build \ Analyze APK, select it. Then check if there is only the file `classes.dex` (not `classes2.dex`), so select this .dex file. And see  the number of references methods exists on it.